# Add file type if a file exists in the root folder

Tags: vim

I'm using a framework `Foo` with a language, let's say `Ruby`.

The project has atleast one file with extension `.foo` present in the root.

Now I want every `.rb` file I open in that session (even if they're in sub folders), to have a file type of `ruby.foo`.

Let's assume that I always open vim in the root folder of the project for this to work, for simplicity.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to append `.foo` to the filetype if `Foo` appears in the file's path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
" Check for a *.foo file in the root directory.
if ! empty(glob('*.foo'))
    " For each opened Ruby file, append the "foo" filetype.
    " Use autocmd-nested to do the filetype processing for "foo".
    " Check for current value to prevent endless loop.
    autocmd FileType ruby nested if &filetype ==# 'ruby' | setlocal filetype=ruby.foo | endif
endif
```

To make this work in any subdirectory, you would need to crawl upwards the directories and perform the `glob()` in each. Though I would delegate this to the [localrc.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393), which allows filetype-specific local configuration. Highly recommended for such project-related settings!

Comment: I think this should work, as I'm only getting this error within folders with .foo files - It says `filetype` is undefined, in the second last line. Any ideas?

Comment: Try changing the `if filetype` to `if &filetype`.

Comment: @RandyMorris: Thanks, I've fixed the typo in my answer.

Comment: do regexes work? i've got a similar problem, and i'd like to run an autocmd if the filename contains a particular string. I am new to vim, so i'm struggling to implement it, but the logic of the problem is `if 'string' %in% expand("%") ...`.